# How to remove decimal value from BarChart MPAndroid Chart? I tried several methods but didn't work

Tags: java, android-studio, label, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7blo.jpg)**I tried all methods but I could not remove the decimal from bar label. How can I remove decimal part from the bar label**

```
      barData.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

            if (value > 0){
                return super.getFormattedValue((int)value);
            }else{
                return "";
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Hi! Do you mean you don't want any numbers (values) on your BarChart?

Comment: So my number looks like 85.0 in bar. I just want to show integer value of 85

Comment: If you round numbers, you will probably lose their accuracy (for example, it is vital in the line chart for a correct graph representation). So I'd recommend to use the specified format.

Comment: Have tried to give float values instead of integer?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the answer:

```
 @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            val df = DecimalFormat("#");
            df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING;
            return df.format(value);
}
```

Combining your code, it should look like this:

```
@Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
          if (value > 0) {
            val df = DecimalFormat("#");
            df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING;
            return df.format(value);
         } else {
            return "";
         } 
}
```

I don't code in Java, so please, check for any syntax misspellings. :)

I reproduced it on my Line chart using Kotlin.

Read more about ValueFormatter in the docs of MPAndroidChart, please: https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/

Comment: It's Worked. Need to take care of Rounding Values in Formator.